# Import dict without name from a module

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

An Odoo module always has the two files `__init__.py` and `__openerp__.py`.

```
dhl_module
          |-- controller
          |-- models
          |-- views
          |-- __init__.py
          |-- __openerp__.py
```

The file `__openerp__.py` contains a dict without assigning it to a name. This dict stores information about the module. It looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
{
    'name': "DHL connector",
    # used as subtitle
    'summary': "Configuration for DHL connector ",
    'description': """ DHL connector
    """,
    'author': "me",
    'website': "mysite.com",
    'category': 'Technical Settings',
    # Change the version every release for apps.
    'version': '0.0.1',
    # any module necessary for this one to work correctly
    'depends': [],
    # always loaded
    'data': ['views/dhl.xml', ],
    # only loaded in demonstration mode
    'demo': [],
    # only loaded in test
    'test': [],
    'installable': True,
    'application': True,
}
```

How can Odoo or I access this dict from the `__openerp__.py` module? The dict variable is not assigned to a name. How can it be imported?

Comment: So `__openerp__.py` doesn't seem to be a valid Python file at all.

Comment: @linusg: it is valid Python, it just doesn't create any new names.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, thanks for information! I checked it, the Python interpreter just does nothing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenERP doesn't have to import that module to get that dictionary. They could just read the file as text and just *evaluate* the contents with `eval()`:

```
>>> text = '''\
... # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
... {
...     'name': "DHL connector",
...     # used as subtitle
...     'summary': "Configuration for DHL connector ",
...     'description': """ DHL connector
...     """,
...     'author': "me",
...     'website': "mysite.com",
...     'category': 'Technical Settings',
...     # Change the version every release for apps.
...     'version': '0.0.1',
...     # any module necessary for this one to work correctly
...     'depends': [],
...     # always loaded
...     'data': ['views/dhl.xml', ],
...     # only loaded in demonstration mode
...     'demo': [],
...     # only loaded in test
...     'test': [],
...     'installable': True,
...     'application': True,
... }
... '''
>>> eval(text)
{'website': 'mysite.com', 'description': ' DHL connector\n    ', 'demo': [], 'depends': [], 'data': ['views/dhl.xml'], 'category': 'Technical Settings', 'name': 'DHL connector', 'author': 'me', 'summary': 'Configuration for DHL connector ', 'application': True, 'version': '0.0.1', 'test': [], 'installable': True}
```

And that is [exactly what OpenERP does](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/7682760dcad232829fbb5d4221f66a1ebb9d6c91/openerp/modules/module.py#L222-L279):

> ```
> MANIFEST = '__openerp__.py'
>
> # ...
>
> terp_file = mod_path and opj(mod_path, MANIFEST) or False
>
> # ...
>
> f = tools.file_open(terp_file)
> try:
>     info.update(eval(f.read()))
> finally:
>     f.close()
> ```